# Secure communication of services within Service Fabric standalone cluster

Tags: security, microservices, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I already have secured Service Fabric cluster (Client to Node and Node to Node) using the following reference doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security

I need to get some help on setting up security for communication between each microservices within an application type inside Service Fabric.

For example I have this sample application with AngularJs front end and two stateful services, service A & service B

Q: What is the best practise to secure the calls from the AngularJS Front End to the Service A and from Service A to B etc.? (red arrows in the diagram below)

[sample application scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IuVP.jpg)

Is there any reference document or book that I can refer

Comment: API gateway (e.g. built in reverse proxy, or your own front facing proxy service)

Comment: Making use of reverse proxy, do you mean based on the following docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy-configure-secure-communication. Using reverse proxy would mean to have reverse proxy configured to listen on HTTPS. I am looking for any other options without using certificates. Do you have a sample project with the implementation of Secured Communication of Services on Service Fabric Cluster on Standalone Windows Server (on premise)

Comment: You need to separate two things, securing ability to connect, and securing the message being sent. they are quite different. Taking securing the message being sent, you'd have to use an SSL certificate or encrypt the payload angular side, and decrypt it in the service fabric. On securing ability to connect, its more an authentication system.